# Use powershell web gui automation to get TD table element

Tags: html, powershell, html-table

I am creating automatic testing using Windows Powershell to test a web gui. I need to get the value out of this:

```
<td> 
    Name:
</td>
<td id = "Name">
    Clark Kent
</td>
```

I was thinking I could access it the same as any other HTML element by using `getElementByID("Name")` but when I run this:

```
$doc = $ie.document
$name = $doc.getElementByID("Name")
write-host $name.value
```

The output is just a blank string; and this:

```
write-host "The field is $name.value"
```

Outputs: "The field is mshtml.HTMLTableCellClass.Value"

Any idea how I would access this value?

Comment: Why don't you use something more highlevel like Watin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops figured out the answer to my own question.

```
$name.IHTMLElement_innerText.Trim()
```

outputs Clark Kent. I needed to trim because otherwise there was a space at the end. I don't know if this was just for my case or for everyone so I included it.